# Question about the word 苦しみ抜いた in the sentence 苦しみ抜いた結果、勝利をもぎ取った

Tags: grammar, compound-verbs

Initially, I thought the word 苦しみ抜いた was just a typical verb that you can search up in the dictionary but apparently that is not the case and so my question is that how does that word come about ? Are there any grammatical rules behind that word or something ?

Answer (score 3):

> 「Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + 抜{ぬ}く」

is a must-remember compound verb meaning:

> "to (verb) thoroughly, completely, to the end, etc."

「苦しみ」 is the 連用形 of the verb 「苦しむ」.  Thus, 「苦しみ抜く」 means "***to suffer thoroughly***" and 「苦しみ抜いた」 is its past-tense form.

The verb 「抜く」 has so many meanings and the above is the 15th meaning/usage of the verb listed in [デジタル大辞泉](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%8A%9C%E3%81%8F-594096#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89).

Definition #15 says:

> 15 （動詞{どうし}の連用形{れんようけい}に付{つ}いて）そのことを最後{さいご}までする。しとおす。また、すっかり…する。しきる。「難工事{なんこうじ}をやり―・く」「がんばり―・く」「ほとほと困{こま}り―・く」

「やりぬく」 and 「がんばりぬく」 are very often used in people's conversations.